# Split into pairs based on delimeter

Tags: php

I have large string of coordinate data similar to the following:

-83.6530304633209,34.8237504877659,-83.65536046332301,34.8248804877671, etc....

I am trying to split this into an array so  can echo it out in a loop like this:

```
new google.maps.LatLng(-83.6530304633209,34.8237504877659)
new google.maps.LatLng(-83.65536046332301,34.8248804877671)
// etc....
```

Anyone know how i could do this in PHP?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$numbers=explode(",",$string);
for ($i=0;$i<=count($numbers)/2;$i+=2)
  echo "new google.maps.LatLng(".$numbers[$i].",".$numbers[$i+1].")";
```

There you go!

Comment: That splits, but doesn't pair the split strings together for lat/long purposes.