# How does one split a string on two delimeters into an associative array

Tags: php, arrays, string

The answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10986283), pointed me in a possible direction, but it processes the string once, then loops through the result. Is there a way to do it in one process?

My string is like this, but much longer:

> ```
> 954_adhesives
> 7_air fresheners
> 25_albums
> 236_stuffed_animial
> 819_antenna toppers
> 69_appliances
> 47_aprons
> 28_armbands
> ```

I'd like to split it on linebreaks, then on underscore so that the number before the underscore is the key and the phrase after the underscore is the value.

Comment: use two explodes - one with `\n`, one with `_`

Comment: You have more than one thing that you need to do the same thing on, the standard thing to do is a loop. You could go *tokenize* the string if you like that better.

Comment: If you don't want to use `regex`, you can still do it in one function using `array_map`. I've given an example in my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a regular expression and [`array_combine`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php):

```
preg_match_all('/^([0-9]+)_(.*)$/m', $input, $matches);
$result = array_combine($matches[1], array_map('trim', $matches[2]));
```

[Sample output](https://eval.in/34884):

```
array(8) {
  [954]=>
  string(9) "adhesives"
  [7]=>
  string(14) "air fresheners"
  [25]=>
  string(6) "albums"
  [236]=>
  string(15) "stuffed_animial"
  [819]=>
  string(15) "antenna toppers"
  [69]=>
  string(10) "appliances"
  [47]=>
  string(6) "aprons"
  [28]=>
  string(8) "armbands"
}
```

Use [`ksort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php) or [`arsort`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php) if you need the result sorted as well, by keys or values respectively.

Comment: That looks like it does exactly what I'm looking for. I'll check it out and, unless there's an even better solution, accept your answer.

Comment: While it's a relatively trivial task to throw regular expressions at, the alternatives require multiple loops so in this case it's likely to be at least as performant.

Comment: As I posted it, I wondered if there was a regex solution. I still avoid them and I know I shouldn't. Then, there's `array_combine()` that I was not familiar with.

Comment: `array_combine` is just a convenient shorthand for `for($i = 0; $i < count($matches[1]); $i++) $result[$matches[1][$i]] = $matches[2][$i];` in this case. It reads better methinks.

Comment: @TecBrat There's a great tool called Rubular (http://rubular.com/) for RegEx testing whih I find to be really helpful.  Watch for different versions (ie, no PCRE support depending on the language), though.

Comment: Thanks. Now I'm working on another problem, but It'd be another question. I'll ask if I don't figure it out, but I realized I have like 555_Trashcans and 555_Wastebaskets and obviously Wastebaskets is going to overwrite Trashcans.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

For posterity, here's my solution.  However, @Niels Keurentjes answer is more appropriate, as it matches a number at the beginning.

---

If you wanted to do this with regular expressions, you could do something like:

```
preg_match_all("/^(.*?)_(.*)$/m", $content, $matches);
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: You forgot to set the multiline flag - the end of string indicator will now make it only parse the last line of the input set.

Comment: Shoot you're absolutely correct. But, your solution is better anyway, as it specifically matches a number at the beginning.

Comment: I also forgot the 'associative array' part hehe since it was only mentioned in the title. Expanded my answer a bit more to fully match the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in one line:
`$result = preg_split('_|\n',$string);`

Here is a handy-dandy tester: http://www.fullonrobotchubby.co.uk/random/preg_tester/preg_tester.php

Answer (score 0):

If you want the result to be a nested array like this;

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 954
            [1] => adhesives
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 7
            [1] => air fresheners
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 25
            [1] => albums
        )

)
```

then you could use an `array_map` eg;

```
$str =
"954_adhesives
7_air fresheners
25_albums";

$arr = array_map(
  function($s) {return explode('_', $s);},
  explode("\n", $str)
);

print_r($arr);
```

I've just used the first three lines of your string for brevity but the same function works ok on the whole string.